# Guardar un dato o almacenarla en una variable de sesion con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, sql

Resulta que tengo un formulario, en el cual un usuario previamente registrado e iniciado sesión, va a poder cambiar o actualizar sus datos de perfil. El tema está en que necesito que el Email, que es con que el usuario inicia sesión, sea almacenado en una **especie de sesión**, para que, con una especie de **consulta SQL**, pueda **mostrar los datos asociados a esa sesión**, o usuario (correo) previamente iniciada la sesión.

**Por Ejemplo:**

> Usuario iniciado sesión: fulanodetal@gmail.com

```
$usuario: 'fulanodetal@gmail.com'; // Dato del usuario iniciado sesión, almacenado en variable $usuario     
$conec = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE Email = '$usuario'";
```

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

***SEGMENTO DE CÓDIGO DE Variables de Sesión***

```
    <?php 

$inc = include ("con_db.php"); 

session_start(); 

$iduser = $_SESSION['Email'];
$_SESSION["Email"][]=$_POST["Email"];
$_POST['Email'] = $email;

?>
```

***SEGMENTO DE CÓDIGO DE Conexión y Consulta SQL***

```
$consulta2 = "SELECT * from datos_personales WHERE Email = '$iduser'"; // "SELECT ID, Nombre, Apellido FROM datos_personales"; Para Mostrar solo campos específicos
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta2);
    $vacio = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta2);
    if ($resultado == true) {
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $imagen = $row['Imagen'];
            $nombre = $row['Nombre'];
            $apellido = $row['Apellido'];
            $telefono = $row['Telefono'];
            $email = $row['Email'];
            $rut = $row['Rut'];
            $region = $row['Region'];
            $password = $row['Password'];
            
    
            
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya intentaste con esto?:

Script "post.php" de Guardado de Sesión enviado desde un formulario:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['Email']; //Guardando fulanodetal@gmail.com en la sesión
/* ... codigo para insertar o actualizar en mysql ... */
```

Script "registro.php" de registro de usuario:

```
session_start();
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex, $_SESSION['email']); //Usando fulanodetal@gmail.com en la sesión
$consulta = "INSERT INTO datos_personales (Email) VALUES ('$email')";
/* ... código para insertar de mysql ... */
```

Script "consulta.php" de uso de Sesión:

```
session_start();
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex, $_SESSION['email']); //Usando fulanodetal@gmail.com en la sesión
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM datos_personales WHERE Email = '$email'";
/* ... código para consultar de mysql ... */
```

*Nota: usé `mysqli_real_escape_string` para escapar los carácteres correctamente en la consulta.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, pero no me sirvió. Parece que no me está tomando la sesión. ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre mysqli_query, y mysqli_real_escape_string?. Porque no creo que sea un tema de consulta, ¿o sí?

Comment: mysqli_query es para ejecutar la consulta, mysqli_real_escape_string convierte un string en otro string pero seguro para concatenar dentro de una consulta ya que escapa las comillas simples por ejemplo, si no te funcionó habría validar como estas enviando la información por POST o por GET desde el formulario.

Comment: También puedes usar `print_r($_POST);` y `print_r($_SESSION);` al principio del script para visualizar que estás enviando y que se está guardando en sesión.

Comment: Gracias otra vez por responder. Creo saber por qué ya no "furula" (funciona xD). Creo, muy posiblemente, que esto se deba a problemas que está teniendo el Hosting con alguno de sus servicios. Lo probaré en localhost, y te aviso cualquier cosa. Saludos... https://i.imgur.com/YAyuPUH.png